# Automatically create enum variants

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I want macros that automatically add structures with attribute macros to the enum.
For example

```rust
#[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
struct A(usize);
#[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
struct B(i32);

#[auto_enum]
enum AutoEnum{}
```

Expand on the above

```rust
struct A(usize);
struct B(i32);

enum AutoEnum{
  A(A),
  B(B),
}
```

I have looked around and could not find a way to get information on other attribute macros (e.g. `#[add_enum(AutoEnum)]` from `#[auto_enum]`).

Is this possible?

Comment: No, I don't believe this is possible without creating a macro that applies to the whole module.

Comment: @cdhowie This is possible, I even think there is some way that is guaranteed to work. I just need to find the crate...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not sure how it would be possible without invoking a module-level macro that actually builds the enum as hygiene will otherwise prevent `A` from meaning the struct `A` in the context of the hypothetical `#[auto_enum]` -- and this is assuming such a macro could even look around at the prior-declared types, which I don't think is possible either.

Comment: @cdhowie Hygiene doesn't apply to items, so this is not a problem. The problem is to know the components.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I recall [reading](https://blog.jetbrains.com/rust/2022/12/05/what-every-rust-developer-should-know-about-macro-support-in-ides/#What_every_Rust_macro_implementor_should_take_into_account) that if you want to stay at least somewhat IDE friendly with your macros, you can't assume anything about in what process, how often, or in what order your macro code will be invoked. That doesn't quite seem to allow for this kind of behavior.

Comment: @Caesar This is definitely true.

Comment: I'm going with crazy ideas. Can you use nightly features?

Comment: A terrible, hacky, [proof of concept](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e04af8b158e72c8d6f86ac4c46b20ff9) that you might have to tweak the magic numbers of. If you don't want nightly you can replace `LazyLock` with something from the once_cell crate or lazy_static

Comment: @cafce25 This is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: If you store them all in one file, you can retrieve the file text and parse it... Ok. I think I'm starting to say nonsense things. This question drives me crazy.

Comment: Thank you all.I look forward to future features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea that will probably don't work in your real code but should work in the example you gave (after a slight modification) so .

As opposed to every other item in Rust, macros can shadow each other. If you will have two macros with the same name, the macro defined later will shadow the first macro.

So, I think... What if we will define macros for all possible names of the enum variant, then shadow them for each actual enum? This will give us a way to expand every variant to what we want.

It will be clearer with an example. Suppose we want to only support letters A-C as variant names, and only support one letter (no `AC`). We first need some place to define the "default" no-variant macros, and it needs to be before any variant. So let's modify the example as follows:

```rust
#[auto_enum(declare)] // New!
enum AutoEnum {}

#[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
struct A(usize);
#[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
struct B(i32);

#[auto_enum(define)] // Changed! (This is not necessary).
enum AutoEnum {}
```

Then, the `#[auto_enum(declare)]` will expand to the following three "default" macros, that pass their input as-is to the next macro except the last macro that creates the final enum:

```rust
macro_rules! AutoEnum_A {
    ( $($t:tt)* ) => { AutoEnum_B! { $($t)* } };
}
macro_rules! AutoEnum_B {
    ( $($t:tt)* ) => { AutoEnum_C! { $($t)* } };
}
macro_rules! AutoEnum_C {
    ( $($t:tt)* ) => {
        enum AutoEnum { $($t)* }
    };
}
```

Now, every `#[add_enum]` call will expand to a macro that shadows the "default" macro, and instead of passing the input to the next macro as-is, it adds its variant to it:

```rust
// #[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
// struct A(usize);
macro_rules! AutoEnum_A {
    ( $($t:tt)* ) => { AutoEnum_B! { $($t)* A(usize), } };
}
// #[add_enum(AutoEnum)]
// struct B(i32);
macro_rules! AutoEnum_B {
    ( $($t:tt)* ) => { AutoEnum_C! { $($t)* B(i32), } };
}
```

Finally, the `#[auto_enum(define)]` will expand to a call to the first macro, a call that eventually at the end of the chain will generate the enum:

```rust
AutoEnum_A! {}
```

Of course, for every letter (assuming you want to support uppercase/lowercase/numbers/underscores) this requires 63 combinations, which means that even supporting 5 letters would require 992436543 macros, so this is not really usable. But still, an interesting idea to explore.

I'm still seeking better ideas that are hopefully also usable.

Comment: This answer is very interesting as an experiment. Thank you very much.